# TextView Scrollable

Tags: android

I set my TextView to be scrollable:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

But, when I update my TextView's texts, the scrolling position keeps at the last text position, resulting in, sometimes, the text getting invisible and then, I need to move the scroll to see the new text (I update with: textView.setText(newText)).

I tried those codes, but no changes were noted:

```
textView.invalidate(); 
textView.requestLayout(); 

textView.scrollBy(0, 0)
textView.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

P.S.: the textView is a child of a RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve my problem:

```
    textView.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            textHeight = textViews.getLineHeight() * textViews.getLineCount();

            if (textHeight > relativeLayout.getHeight()) 
                textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
            else 
                textView.setMovementMethod(null);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a ScrollView in xml will be much easier open the ScrollView open a layout set it how you want it to be horizontal or vertical put your TextViews in and then close first the layout and then ScrollView and Voila done..